# Quartz-- on cloud server kicking of multiple threads

Tags: java, cloud, tomcat6, quartz-scheduler

We have a system where we set up the quartz thread count to 1, indicating 1 thread at a time. This works fine on our local servers and kicks of 1 thread at a time (trigger based on link from web ui),even though the user clicks the same trigger multiple times(the triggers are put in a queue).

However, we are migrating to a new cloud server and this trigger when clicked multiple times tends to click off multiple threads(without actually putting the eventual threads in queue).

We are using Tomcat6 and Java 6.There is no clustering/load balancing on the server. Any ideas/input would of great help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Quartz, but in Java you can use a thread pool with an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). There are different executor services so you will need look at documentation and see which ones meets your needs. (Perhaps try `newFixedThreadPool(int)`)